# Screenshot WinAPI - Free Memory

Tags: c, winapi, memory-leaks, screenshot

I already asked a very similar question one or two days ago but my problem wasn't very clear, so I try to reformulate it here:

I want to do a screenshot of my screen and to do that I searched and found this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

inline int GetFilePointer(HANDLE FileHandle)
{
    return SetFilePointer(FileHandle, 0, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
}

extern _Bool SaveBMPFile(char* filePath, HBITMAP bitmap, HDC bitmapDC, int width, int height)
{
    _Bool Success = 0;
    HDC SurfDC = NULL;        // GDI-compatible device context for the surface
    HBITMAP OffscrBmp = NULL; // bitmap that is converted to a DIB
    HDC OffscrDC = NULL;      // offscreen DC that we can select OffscrBmp into
    LPBITMAPINFO lpbi = NULL; // bitmap format info; used by GetDIBits
    LPVOID lpvBits = NULL;    // pointer to bitmap bits array
    HANDLE BmpFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;    // destination .bmp file
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;  // .bmp file header

                            // We need an HBITMAP to convert it to a DIB:
    if ((OffscrBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(bitmapDC, width, height)) == NULL)
        return 0;

    // The bitmap is empty, so let's copy the contents of the surface to it.
    // For that we need to select it into a device context. We create one.
    if ((OffscrDC = CreateCompatibleDC(bitmapDC)) == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Select OffscrBmp into OffscrDC:
    HBITMAP OldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(OffscrDC, OffscrBmp);

    // Now we can copy the contents of the surface to the offscreen bitmap:
    BitBlt(OffscrDC, 0, 0, width, height, bitmapDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // GetDIBits requires format info about the bitmap. We can have GetDIBits
    // fill a structure with that info if we pass a NULL pointer for lpvBits:
    // Reserve memory for bitmap info (BITMAPINFOHEADER + largest possible
    // palette):
    if ((lpbi = (LPBITMAPINFO)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD))) == NULL)
        return 0;


    ZeroMemory(&lpbi->bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    // Get info but first de-select OffscrBmp because GetDIBits requires it:
    SelectObject(OffscrDC, OldBmp);
    if (!GetDIBits(OffscrDC, OffscrBmp, 0, height, NULL, lpbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        return 0;

    // Reserve memory for bitmap bits:
    if ((lpvBits = malloc(lpbi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage)) == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Have GetDIBits convert OffscrBmp to a DIB (device-independent bitmap):
    if (!GetDIBits(OffscrDC, OffscrBmp, 0, height, lpvBits, lpbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        return 0;


    //ANSI->Unicode
    LPCSTR szAnsi = filePath;
    int Size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szAnsi, -1, NULL, 0);
    LPWSTR filename = malloc(sizeof(LPWSTR) * Size);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szAnsi, -1, filename, Size);
    // Create a file to save the DIB to:
    if ((BmpFile = CreateFile(filename,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0, NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

        return 0;

    DWORD Written;    // number of bytes written by WriteFile

                      // Write a file header to the file:
    bmfh.bfType = 19778;        // 'BM'
                                // bmfh.bfSize = ???        // we'll write that later
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    // bmfh.bfOffBits = ???     // we'll write that later
    if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, &bmfh, sizeof(bmfh), &Written, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (Written < sizeof(bmfh))
        return 0;

    // Write BITMAPINFOHEADER to the file:
    if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, &lpbi->bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &Written, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (Written < sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER))
        return 0;

    // Calculate size of palette:
    int PalEntries;
    // 16-bit or 32-bit bitmaps require bit masks:
    if (lpbi->bmiHeader.biCompression == BI_BITFIELDS)
        PalEntries = 3;
    else
        // bitmap is palettized?
        PalEntries = (lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount <= 8) ?
        // 2^biBitCount palette entries max.:
        (int)(1 << lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount)
        // bitmap is TrueColor -> no palette:
        : 0;
    // If biClrUsed use only biClrUsed palette entries:
    if (lpbi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed)
        PalEntries = lpbi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed;

    // Write palette to the file:
    if (PalEntries) {
        if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, &lpbi->bmiColors, PalEntries * sizeof(RGBQUAD), &Written, NULL))
            return 0;

        if (Written < PalEntries * sizeof(RGBQUAD))
            return 0;
    }

    // The current position in the file (at the beginning of the bitmap bits)
    // will be saved to the BITMAPFILEHEADER:
    bmfh.bfOffBits = GetFilePointer(BmpFile);

    // Write bitmap bits to the file:
    if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, lpvBits, lpbi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage, &Written, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (Written < lpbi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage)
        return 0;

    // The current pos. in the file is the final file size and will be saved:
    bmfh.bfSize = GetFilePointer(BmpFile);

    // We have all the info for the file header. Save the updated version:
    SetFilePointer(BmpFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, &bmfh, sizeof(bmfh), &Written, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (Written < sizeof(bmfh))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}



_Bool ScreenCapture(char* filePath, int xStart, int yStart, int width, int height)
{
    // get a DC compat. w/ the screen
    HDC hDc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);

    // make a bmp in memory to store the capture in
    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), width, height);

    // join em up
    SelectObject(hDc, hBmp);

    // copy from the screen to my bitmap
    BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, width, height, GetDC(0), xStart, yStart, SRCCOPY);

    // save my bitmap
    _Bool ret = SaveBMPFile(filePath, hBmp, hDc, width, height);

    // free the bitmap memory
    DeleteObject(hBmp);

    return ret;
}

main()
{
    ScreenCapture("screenshot.bmp", 0, 0, 1920, 1080);

    FILE* Screen = NULL;
    Screen = fopen("screenshot.bmp", "r"); //Error, the image is "used" somewhere...     

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know a word of the WinAPI but I saw in Viual Studio that at each call to ScreenCapture(), there's non-freed RAM and that's a problem.

If some of you knows where's the error...

Appreciates help, thanks :)

Comment: You don't close `BmpFile`.  Before returning from `SaveBMPFile` call `CloseHandle(BmpFile);`

Comment: Yeah, *all* those objects you create need to be freed/destroyed. There is a corresponding function to do that for each creation function. You'll find it listed in the MSDN documentation for the creation function.

Comment: Thank you ! That's done, no more problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), width, height);`

`GetDC(0)` must be cleaned up with `ReleasedDC`. When you write `GetDC(0)` in that way, it is impossible to clean up. You only have 10,000 GDI handles available to your program, so this resource leak can be a serious problem.

You should do instead:

```
HDC hdc_desktop = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc_desktop, width, height);
...
ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc_desktop);
```

`HWND_DESKTOP` is just `0`, I used it for clarity. `GetDC` returns a handle `hdc_desktop` which can be cleaned up at the end.

`DeleteObject(hBmp)` is a minor bug, because `hBmp` is currently selected in `hDc` and cannot be deleted. A lot of programmers make this mistake, so newer Windows versions (I think since XP) have come to expect this, so Windows fixes this bug (at least in this situation) but you should really save a handle to the old bitmap, restore the old bitmap, and then delete the new bitmap.

There is another minor bug with `GetDIBits`. Documentation says hbitmap must not be selected in to dc when the function is called. But again Windows is used to seeing this error and fixes it.

Your `SaveBMPFile` can be simplified. You are not saving a palette bitmap, you can ignore the palette completely.

Unreleated issues: You are using Unicode functions, so you UTF-16 string literals: `L"screenshot.bmp"` instead of `"screenshot.bmp"`

```
extern _Bool SaveBMPFile(const wchar_t* filePath, 
    HDC memdc, HBITMAP hbitmap, int width, int height)
{
    _Bool success = 0;
    WORD bpp = 24; //or 32 for 32-bit bitmap
    DWORD size = ((width * bpp + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

    BITMAPFILEHEADER filehdr = { 0 };
    filehdr.bfType = 19778;
    filehdr.bfSize = 54 + size;
    filehdr.bfOffBits = 54; 
    //54 = 14 + 40, sizeof BITMAPFILEHEADER & BITMAPINFOHEADER

    BITMAPINFOHEADER infohdr = { sizeof(infohdr) };
    infohdr.biWidth = width;
    infohdr.biHeight = height;
    infohdr.biPlanes = 1;
    infohdr.biBitCount = bpp;

    BYTE *bits = malloc(size);
    GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, height, bits, (BITMAPINFO*)&infohdr, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    HANDLE hfile = CreateFileW(filePath,
        GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if(hfile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DWORD temp;
        WriteFile(hfile, &filehdr, 14, &temp, NULL);
        WriteFile(hfile, &infohdr, 40, &temp, NULL);
        WriteFile(hfile, bits, size, &temp, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hfile);
        success = 1;
    }

    free(bits);    
    return success;
}

_Bool ScreenCapture(const wchar_t* filePath, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);
    HBITMAP oldbitmap = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, x, y, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(memdc, oldbitmap);

    _Bool ret = SaveBMPFile(filePath, memdc, hbitmap, width, height);

    DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);

    return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
    ScreenCapture(L"screenshot.bmp", 0, 0, 
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN));
    return 0;
}
```

You can run this in a loop and watch GDI handles in Taskman to make sure there is no leak.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the final code, working without problems, working without memory leaks:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Helper function to retrieve current position of file pointer:
inline int GetFilePointer(HANDLE FileHandle)
{
    return SetFilePointer(FileHandle, 0, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Screenshot
//    -> FileName: Name of file to save screenshot to
//    -> lpDDS: DirectDraw surface to capture
//    <- Result: Success
//
extern _Bool SaveBMPFile(char* filePath, HBITMAP bitmap, HDC bitmapDC, int width, int height)
{
    _Bool Success = 0;
    HBITMAP OffscrBmp = NULL; // bitmap that is converted to a DIB
    HDC OffscrDC = NULL;      // offscreen DC that we can select OffscrBmp into
    LPBITMAPINFO lpbi = NULL; // bitmap format info; used by GetDIBits
    LPVOID lpvBits = NULL;    // pointer to bitmap bits array
    HANDLE BmpFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;    // destination .bmp file
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;  // .bmp file header

                            // We need an HBITMAP to convert it to a DIB:
    if ((OffscrBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(bitmapDC, width, height)) == NULL)
        return 0;

    // The bitmap is empty, so let's copy the contents of the surface to it.
    // For that we need to select it into a device context. We create one.
    if ((OffscrDC = CreateCompatibleDC(bitmapDC)) == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Select OffscrBmp into OffscrDC:
    HBITMAP OldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(OffscrDC, OffscrBmp);

    // Now we can copy the contents of the surface to the offscreen bitmap:
    BitBlt(OffscrDC, 0, 0, width, height, bitmapDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // GetDIBits requires format info about the bitmap. We can have GetDIBits
    // fill a structure with that info if we pass a NULL pointer for lpvBits:
    // Reserve memory for bitmap info (BITMAPINFOHEADER + largest possible
    // palette):
    if ((lpbi = (LPBITMAPINFO)malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 256 * sizeof(RGBQUAD))) == NULL)
        return 0;


    ZeroMemory(&lpbi->bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    lpbi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    // Get info but first de-select OffscrBmp because GetDIBits requires it:
    SelectObject(OffscrDC, OldBmp);
    if (!GetDIBits(OffscrDC, OffscrBmp, 0, height, NULL, lpbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        return 0;

    // Reserve memory for bitmap bits:
    if ((lpvBits = malloc(lpbi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage)) == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Have GetDIBits convert OffscrBmp to a DIB (device-independent bitmap):
    if (!GetDIBits(OffscrDC, OffscrBmp, 0, height, lpvBits, lpbi, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
        return 0;


    //ANSI->Unicode
    LPCSTR szAnsi = filePath;
    int Size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szAnsi, -1, NULL, 0);
    LPWSTR filename = malloc(sizeof(LPWSTR) * Size);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szAnsi, -1, filename, Size);
    // Create a file to save the DIB to:
    if ((BmpFile = CreateFile(filename,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0, NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)

        return 0;

    DWORD Written;    // number of bytes written by WriteFile

                      // Write a file header to the file:
    bmfh.bfType = 19778;        // 'BM'
                                // bmfh.bfSize = ???        // we'll write that later
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    // bmfh.bfOffBits = ???     // we'll write that later
    if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, &bmfh, sizeof(bmfh), &Written, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (Written < sizeof(bmfh))
        return 0;

    // Write BITMAPINFOHEADER to the file:
    if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, &lpbi->bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &Written, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (Written < sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER))
        return 0;

    // Calculate size of palette:
    int PalEntries;
    // 16-bit or 32-bit bitmaps require bit masks:
    if (lpbi->bmiHeader.biCompression == BI_BITFIELDS)
        PalEntries = 3;
    else
        // bitmap is palettized?
        PalEntries = (lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount <= 8) ?
        // 2^biBitCount palette entries max.:
        (int)(1 << lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount)
        // bitmap is TrueColor -> no palette:
        : 0;
    // If biClrUsed use only biClrUsed palette entries:
    if (lpbi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed)
        PalEntries = lpbi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed;

    // Write palette to the file:
    if (PalEntries) {
        if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, &lpbi->bmiColors, PalEntries * sizeof(RGBQUAD), &Written, NULL))
            return 0;

        if (Written < PalEntries * sizeof(RGBQUAD))
            return 0;
    }

    // The current position in the file (at the beginning of the bitmap bits)
    // will be saved to the BITMAPFILEHEADER:
    bmfh.bfOffBits = GetFilePointer(BmpFile);

    // Write bitmap bits to the file:
    if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, lpvBits, lpbi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage, &Written, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (Written < lpbi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage)
        return 0;

    // The current pos. in the file is the final file size and will be saved:
    bmfh.bfSize = GetFilePointer(BmpFile);

    // We have all the info for the file header. Save the updated version:
    SetFilePointer(BmpFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    if (!WriteFile(BmpFile, &bmfh, sizeof(bmfh), &Written, NULL))
        return 0;

    if (Written < sizeof(bmfh))
        return 0;

    DeleteObject(OffscrBmp);
    DeleteObject(OldBmp);
    DeleteDC(OffscrDC);
    CloseHandle(BmpFile);

    free(lpbi);
    free(lpvBits);
    free(filename);

    return 1;
}

_Bool ScreenCapture(char* filePath, int xStart, int yStart, int width, int height)
{
    // get a DC compat. w/ the screen
    HDC hDc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);

    // make a bmp in memory to store the capture in
    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), width, height);

    // join em up
    SelectObject(hDc, hBmp);

    // copy from the screen to my bitmap
    BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, width, height, GetDC(0), xStart, yStart, SRCCOPY);

    // save my bitmap
    _Bool ret = SaveBMPFile(filePath, hBmp, hDc, width, height);

    // free the bitmap memory
    DeleteObject(hBmp);
    DeleteDC(hDc);

    return ret;
}

main()
{
    ScreenCapture("screenshot.png", 0, 0, 1920, 1080);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code anyway mistaken, and you will fail free resource on any error

Comment: There were memory leaks at every call to ScreenCapture, there's no memory leak anymore. Maybe there's still some errors but I can't fix the code... Don't know the WinAPI

Comment: There is still leaks here. The code is saving bitmap, not PNG. If this was C++ then you could use GDI+ or COM to save png file. Otherwise you need another C compatible library to save PNG.